# Apache tomcat - how to open the browser in remote machine

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, war, vnc

I have a local machine , say A with IP (a.a.a.a) and a linux server, say B with IP (b.b.b.b)
Now I have created a war file with name 'example' and deployed it in Apache tomcat in our linux server.
I want to open the browser in my local machine by typing the following in address bar :
http://b.b.b.b:8080/example

But I am not able to open it.
Could any one please suggest where in lies the issue?
Note : We can connect from A to B using only VNC viewer  and not able to connect it through remote desktop connection application.

Does this implies that there is some issue in network connectivity or what? I think as we are able to connect B using VNC viewer, the problem should not be there.

Please help.

++++++++++++++++

extended

I have installed the apache tomcat server in my linux server which doesnot have any internet connecttion and deployed the war file in the server successfully.
and want to open browser from my local machine using (linux_IP)//8080//war_file_name
Note : local machine connects linux server through VNC only.

Could any one suggest is it possible in this scenario?

Comment: is `http://b.b.b.b:8080/example` reachable from b? use wget or curl  to find out.

Comment: Do you get an response if you use `http://b.b.b.b:8080/`? If yes look to your server if the war is depled without error.

Comment: What do you mean 'not able to open it'? Are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: I am not getting any error too

Comment: Any firewalls in the network?

Comment: Hi Jens, http://b.b.b.b:8080/ is opening fine. How will I check for war file deployed correctly and what needs to check for this? please suggest

Answer (score 0):

If you can only open server B using VNC, then there is a definite possibility that port 8080 is not open. The port 8080 should be open on the server. To check that you could try :

```
telnet host port
```

so for you:

```
telnet b.b.b.b 8080
```

from your machine.

Another thing to do is to start tomcat with IP address of your linux server to listen. Start tomcat with parameters:

`-b b.b.b.b` (ip address of your linux machine).

To me if definitely feels like a firewall problem.